# Is it possible with DataGrip to add a row containing a foreign key and navigate to referenced table to select it?

Tags: datagrip, intellij-datagrip

In some database client (e.g. postico), when you add a new row using the GUI, it's still possible to search and select the id of the referenced table.

I'm using DataGrip and I could not find an equivalent. I've been through the documentation and could not find anything. Did I search correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually on the issue tracker:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-1912